# Acceso Prohibido, Xampp en EC2 amazon

Tags: laravel, xampp, apache2

Tengo un EC2 de amazon (windows server) en donde se ha instalado xampp para correr aplicaciones PHP, se ha implementado ademas un certificado de seguridad SSL en el xampp, el asunto es que hay ahí otras aplicaciones desarrollado por otro programador y que están corriendo sin problemas, mientras que el aplicativo que acabamos de subir desarrollado en laravel nos da el error 403 acceso prohibido.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de esto, ya se trato de dar permisos de lectura a las carpetas pero nada.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la configuración de tu Apache, que tenga esta configuración

```
<Directory "/home/domain/www">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
                Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```